# Node JS installation error: Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: node.js, windows-7, installation

I just want to install nodejs, that's all and it's not like this is the first time. I just un-installed and downloaded the latest version to re-install and I keep getting this error. Is there any fix for this?

I'm doing this on Windows 7 SP1 x64. And yes I've tried both 64 and 32-bit versions still the same issue. See screenshot

[image]

Okay I also monitored the installation logs and I noticed this:

```
MSI (s) (68:6C) [11:32:08:140]: SECREPAIR: SourceHash database file already exists. Deleting it.
...
MSI (s) (68:6C) [11:33:19:147]: SECUREREPAIR: Failed to CreateContentHash of the file: node-v0.10.31-x64.msi: for computing its hash. Error: -2146893813
MSI (s) (68:6C) [11:33:19:147]: SECREPAIR: Failed to create hash for the install source files
MSI (s) (68:6C) [11:33:19:147]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SourceHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (68:6C) [11:33:19:147]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 8009000bECA934B8
```

Does this have anything to do with it?

Comment: Okay so after some research I found an issue with windows 7 update KB2918614 causing overlapped I/O operation.. did a roll back, installed nodejs and updated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two suggestions from [others who have had the same issue](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Key+not+valid+for+use+in+specified+state%22+msi):

- Rename `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA` to something else like `"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA.old"` and try the installer again.
- You may want to check to see if you have the [KB2918614](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2918614) update installed. On Windows 7 you can check by looking through `Control Panel` -> `Programs and Features` -> `View Installed Updates`. Try uninstalling that update and try the installer again.

Comment: I had actually tried the second option before I saw your comment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The first option works too. I'll actually recommend the first. Renaming the RSA folder. But why didn't Microsoft fix this in their subsequent updates?